# Redirect all unknown subdomains https on specific subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I've a trouble with apache. I would like redirect all unknown subdomains on specific subdomain, like that:

```
http://unknown.domain.com => http://oops.domain.com
http://domain.com => http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com => http://www.domain.com
http://sub.domain.com => http://sub.domain.com
```

If I've understood correctly, apache catch the first vhost if it unknown subdomain. So I configure the file 000-default like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://oops.clozly.com [L,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

It's work, but not with https :(
I using let's encrypt, I test to build a 000-default-ssl :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://oops.clozly.com [L,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work... The result is:

```
https://unknown.domain.com => [NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID] => http://unknown.domain.com
```

Thanks you very much for all.
G.

Comment: Do not redirect the challenge to a https site, it won't work...